# Composite key vs extra unique column

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, composite-key, unique-constraint

Are there any major overhead differences between using a `UNIQUE` constraint on two columns and simply having one column that contains the concatenation of the two column values/GUID and using an index on that? For example, instead of using `|John|Smith|` (two different columns) as the unique constraint, would it be more efficient to add an extra column that holds `JohnSmith` or a random GUID?

Comment: That would break for `Johnny | Smith` and `John | Nysmith`

Comment: The real data won't be likely to have that, but the search could be made case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating the two columns for use as a key seems silly -- the database is perfectly capable of doing that for you when you declare the composite key.  Whether it makes sense to add an additional INT or GUID key to the table depends on whether the two columns really *are* the primary key to the table.  If they are, why carry around the extra overhead of an additional column (you still need the index on the first two columns to ensure they stay unique).  But if they're not a real primary key (as in your example, first name and last name cannot be considered a primary key in almost any real world system) then you will need a separate primary key.

Comment: The PK is an incrementing int (to support existing data access code), but the data coming in has no single unique property (although I can append a GUID to it). I'm not sure if I should add a GUID column, and append a GUID to the data, or combine two columns to check if the data coming in is unique.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with adding those two columns and define a unique constraint on them as they seem to have business relevance and a GUID doesn't seem to be suitable. Also, the motivation to NOT combine them is to avoid any `SUBSTRING` operations at a later point to process them separately.

Answer (score 1):

There wouldn't be much difference in the index itself, but adding the extra field to the table would make each record larger and thus make any operation on the table slower because of the additional I/O.